# I can't follow links from the h bar chatroom to meta.PSE. What's going wrong?

Tags: bug

Whenever I click a hyperlink to meta.PSE (as posted by e.g. the "Physics Meta" bot) in the h bar, I get the following screen:

[image]

When I choose to proceed anyways (bottom hyperlink), I get this:

[image]

Note that the URL looks like this:

[image]

Some other times, I just immediately get this screen:

[image]

I do manage to get to the correct page by simply deleting the `https://` part of the URL and pressing enter. What's going wrong? For reference, I'm on Windows 10, using Google Chrome.

Comment: Can you point to a specific example of a link on h bar to `https://meta.*`? The https on meta issue is well known, but there's no reason for links on chat to go there, particularly if they've been automatically generated, and it's not like people would be copy-pasting from their address bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is [well known](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265918/accessing-per-site-metas-gives-403-forbidden-from-cloudflare-nginx), and has been for years. The problem is simply that you cannot access any Stack Exchange meta sites using HTTPS. It has nothing to do with chat, or your browser.

In detail, in order to access a site using HTTPS (an encrypted connection), the site needs to provide a certificate which contains the site's name, an associated encryption key, and a certification that these values are associated with each other. The certificate specification allows a single leading wildcard; for example, it's possible to make a certificate that gives one encryption key to be used by any domain of the form `*.stackexchange.com` (where `*` can be anything). But it's not possible to make a certificate that can be used by `meta.*.stackexchange.com`, or `*.*.stackexchange.com`, which is what would be needed to make the meta sites accessible over HTTPS. The certification process StackExchange uses is expensive, and they understandably don't want to go through it to get a separate certificate for each meta site.

Until Stack Exchange changes their site architecture to solve the problem (if they ever do), a workaround *may* be to use the [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/HTTPS-everywhere) extension, if it's available for your browser. Its main purpose is to enforce HTTPS usage; it prevents your browser from making unencrypted connections to certain sites which are known to work with HTTPS. But as a side effect, I *believe* it also prevents the browser from making encrypted connections to a few sites which are known *not* to work with HTTPS, including the SE meta sites.